# What defines an "isolated" test?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a class called `Customer` and I wish to unit test this class and its public interface. To be able to *unit test*, I have to test `Customer` in isolation from its *real* dependencies. Other than `Customer`, I have a `Monster` class that I have created.

My application is using a game framework that defines a `Shape` (represents a shape) and `Vec2F` (represents a vector used for math). `Customer` relies(uses) on `Shape` and `Vec2F`. It also uses a `Monster`.

Now I have to mock these real dependencies for my tests to be unit tests and not integration tests. However, what defines "real" dependencies? Like I would understand why I would mock my own implementation of `Monster` but `Vec2F` and `Shape` from the framework I use seem to be such fundamental structures.

Answer (score 2):

Tests should be isolated from other tests. For this you need to mock any global state consumed by the system under the test.

If system under the test doesn't use global/shared state - mock nothing.
In perfect world, where setup new database will take a milliseconds, you can create new database for every test (In-Memory database in EF Core).

But in our real world we have dependencies which represents global state or if not, still will make tests slow(web services, file system, any external resources).

Those dependencies you wanna mock to provide quicker feedback(unit tests).

You can have very complicated dependencies hierarchy, which don't use global state or external resources, but configuring a test case with those dependencies, will become very very complex and difficult.
In this case you will introduce an abstraction around very very complex dependency and will mock it in the consumer's tests.

In your particular test case, I would mock nothing, unless framework classes depend on the drawing screen logic(depend on environment API).

Answer (score 1):

Since testing software is a huge task, you split it into several tasks to make it manageable.  In unit-testing your focus is on finding bugs that can be found by looking at small software pieces in isolation.  That is, unit-testing aims at finding a special kind of bugs.  Integration testing, for example, aims at a different kind of bugs, which can not be found by unit-testing.

Focusing on finding the bugs in an isolated piece of software does *not* mean you really must isolate that piece of software technically by mocking the dependencies.  Nowadays mocking frameworks make mocking fairly easy (the level of difficulty varies among programming languages, though).  Still, mocking is always some extra effort and also comes with disadvantages.  For example, tests that use mocking are more closely linked to the code's implementation and thus are more likely to need maintainenance if implementation details change.

Therefore, mocking should only be done if there is a good reason to mock.  Good reasons are:

- You can not easily make the depended-on-component (DOC) behave as intended for your tests.
- Does calling the DOC cause any non-derministic behaviour (date/time, randomness, network connections)?
- The test setup is overly complex and/or maintenance intensive (like, need for external files)
- The original DOC brings portability problems for your test code.
- Does using the original DOC cause unnacceptably long build / execution times?
- Has the DOC stability (maturity) issues that make the tests unreliable, or, worse, is the DOC not even available yet?

For example, you (typically) don't mock standard library math functions like `sin` or `cos`, because they don't have any of the abovementioned problems.  The same could hold, in your case for `Vec2F` and `Shape`, but you would have to judge that by yourself.  The above list of criteria should help you there.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `Customer` is a domain level type. In this case, you should invert the dependency to `Shape` and `Vec2F` (this looks like the view-layer implementation) since the framework is a detail and it is on a lower level than the `Customer` is.